# Yii -Class 'frontend\controllers\UserForm' not found error

Tags: php, yii2

Yii frame work
I place  `UserFrom.php` in  root/models folder code is bellow

```
<?
namespace app\models;
use yii\base\Model;

class UserForm extends Model
{

    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return[[['name','email'],'required'],
                ['email','email'],]
    }

}

?>
```

and  modifi the `root/frontend/controllers/ Sitecontroller.php` file . add the following code

```
public function actionUser()
{
    $model=new UserForm;
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->valideate())
    {

    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('userForm',['model'=>$model] );
    }
}
```

then finaly add  new file in `root/views/site/userForm.php` its code bellow

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form=ActiveForm::begin();?>
<?php $form->field($model,'name'); ?>
<?php $form->field($model,'email'); ?>
<?php Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']);
```

> if i open the url i am getting error 
>   url=http://localhost/yiicomm/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/user
>
> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>   Class 'frontend\controllers\UserForm' not found. 
>   i feel i placed correcly but get error . what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 7):

Try using the full namespace:

```
$model=new \app\models\UserForm;
```

Or include the following line at top of your controller:

```
use app\models\UserForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the [Use Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) to get the fully qualified name for your class UserForm e.g

`use app\models\Userform;`

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
use app\models\UserForm;
```

in your Controller